# how to traverse in the plist

Tags: iphone, plist

How can I traverse in the plist to get the value number?

My plist looks like this:

```
Arrays
  Array
    Dictionary
       Number
       Number
  Array
    ...
```

So in code, I've already started something:

```
NSString *imagePlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Imageinfo" ofType:@"plist"];    
NSArray *imageArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imagePlist];
```

I don't know what's next??? Pls advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have an `NSArray`... Look for `objectAtIndex:` or use: `for (NSArray *secondLevelArray in imageArray) { ...do something with secondLevelArray... }`

And for `NSDictionary`, `objectForKey:` or `for (id key in dict) {...}` or whatever you want.

For `NSNumber`: `[number intValue]` or float or double or whatever you need.

Comment: ok... I've forgot this.. what if inside the second level array are dictionaries? how u should traverse into it? still objectForKey: ?

Comment: You could say `for (NSDictionary *dict in secondLevelArray) {...}`

Comment: yes..got it already.. thanks... btw, i've just seen you in iphonedev irc channel..thanks anyway. :)